# Auth0 UWP client - don't show previously logged in user

Tags: c#, uwp, auth0

I am using the Auth0 client for UWP as described here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/windows-uwp-csharp/01-login.

Everything is working fine, but for my application it is a security risk to show the previously logged in user screen when the Auth0 window appears, and I am wondering if there is a way to change this.

**Edit:** I've tried

```
 // Create an instance of the Auth0 client
     Auth0Client client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
     {
           Domain = resources.GetString("Auth0Domain"),
           ClientId = resources.GetString("Auth0ClientID"),
           LoadProfile = false
     });

     IdentityModel.OidcClient.LoginResult loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();

     // Access the logged in user's data
     if (!loginResult.IsError)
     {
           ...
     }
```

Comment: Previously? Or currently logged in user?

Comment: @cloudikka Previously. When the Auth0 window appears, it says something like "Last time you logged in with..." and shows the last user's email. You can log in with that user without even entering the password.

Comment: can you share mainpage.xaml content?

Comment: Or it is shown in the popup?

Comment: @cloudikka In the Auth0 popup, in my code I literally only have: `await client.LoginAsync();`, but I was wondering if maybe you can set some options during client initialization...

Comment: I am reviewing it. There is an API endpoint to remove user(seems not relevant), but I am not able to find it in the Auth0Client. Gimme few minutes.

Comment: Can you try to set LoadProfile property on Auth0Options to false. By default it is true and may cause you see the last logged in user. Let me know.

Comment: @cloudikka Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code so I can try at my computer?

Comment: @cloudikka I've edited my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162095/discussion-between-cloudikka-and-eutherpy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize login page on Auth0 Dashboard navigating to Hosted Pages and enabling Customize Login Page and set `rememberLastLogin: false` in content.

Related links:

[Custom Login Page(login required)](https://manage.auth0.com/#/login_page)